# Can't get why adding link to modal is crashing my view and showing strange content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using Rails, Twitter Bootstrap and Devise gem.

Maybe my principe of calling modals is bad, but it worked, so I will explain where is problem.

Here is my header:

```
  <div class="modal hide" id="login">
   <%= render :template => "devise/sessions/new" %>
  </div>
 <div class="modal hide" id="sign_up">
   <%= render :template => "devise/registrations/new" %>
 </div>
 <div class="modal hide" id="congrats">
  <%= render :template => "devise/registrations/congrats" %>
 </div>
```

And all is working, modals are calling from modals(when user want to get Sign Up form from login),

**BUT when I add this line:**

```
    <div class="modal hide" id="forgot_password">
     <%= render :template => "devise/passwords/new"%>
   </div>
```

My view starts showing only header.

Here is code from devise/passwords/new:

```
      <div class="login_header">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
<%= image_tag("/images/close_btn.png") %>
```

```
<%= image_tag("/images/login_logo.png") %>
 <div class="login_header_text">
 <h2>Forgot your password?</h2>
 <hr id="line">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form_for_new">
 <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :post }) do |f| %>
 <%= devise_error_messages! %>
 <div class="field2">
 <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
 </div>
 <div class="login_submit">
   <%= f.submit "Send me", class: "btn login" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

And I call it from login modal:

```
         <b><%= link_to("Forgot?", "#forgot_password", "data-toggle" => "modal") %></b>
```

in modal showing all content(home page) with forgot password form.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Not sure, but you may have an unclosed `<div>` somewhere.

Comment: Michał Szajbe, your suggestion didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note my comments below. You have not closed the div3

```
<div class="login_header">                                    #open div1
   <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
   <%= image_tag("/images/close_btn.png") %>
   <%= image_tag("/images/login_logo.png") %>
   <div class="login_header_text">                            #open div2
     <h2>Forgot your password?</h2>
     <hr id="line">
   </div>                                                     #close div2
 </div>                                                       #close div1
 <div class="form_for_new">                                   #open div3
   <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :post }) do |f| %>
   <%= devise_error_messages! %>
   <div class="field2">                                       #open div4
     <%= f.label :email %><br />
     <%= f.email_field :email %>
   </div>                                                     #close div4
   <div class="login_submit">                                 #open div5
     <%= f.submit "Send me", class: "btn login" %>
   </div>                                                     #close div 5
 <% end %>
```